# Organizing a map of strings by one string in the structure golang

Tags: mongodb, sorting, dictionary, go, dynamic

I have a structure of notifications, which looks like:

```
type Notification struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId  //unique id for this notification
    ClientID    bson.ObjectId //this identifies the client attached to
    Description string   //notification message
    Date        string   //date using time.Now()
}
```

So in practice, I have a jumbled collection of data, for example: 
"User1 has been invited", 
"User3 has accepted their invite", 
"User2 has made a payment",
"User3 has made a payment",
"User1 has accepted their invite", etc, etc...

QUESTION: I don't know how many clients I may have at one time, but I want to be able to search the struct and find out how many unique ClientID's I have. My objective is to start creating a dynamic map where I'm attaching all of the notifications to their individual clients.

The final goal is to be able to pass to the front end (GoLang Template) a display report that looks like this?

ClientID(User1):
"User1 has been invited",
"User1 has accepted their invite"

ClientID(User2):
"User2 has made a payment"

ClientID(User3):
"User3 has accepted their invite",
"User3 has made a payment"

Comment: What are you having trouble with? It sounds like you'd want a map using `ClientID` as the key, with the element type being a slice of  `Notification` (or `*Notification`).

Comment: Yes, that is it! The only other example I have is to create a dynamic Map when I know I have a set number of fields to organize them by. But now I don't know how may users I might have when I want to generate this report.

Comment: Like this? https://play.golang.org/p/gJ1x7nw0VK